# discrete math question for ratio

Tags: combinatorics, ratio

From n men and n women one wants to select k male and k female candidates, to create either a committee or a ballot. In a ballot the members are fully ranked (first, second, ...); in a committee they remain unranked. 
Let Bk be the number of possible ballots and Ck - the number of possible committees. Find the ratio Bk/Ck.

(k!)2  **or** (2k)! **or** k out of 2k?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:  Do you know how many ways to choose $k$ men out of $n$ candidates, ordered and unordered?  Now you have to combine that with a selection of women.

Comment: Is that c(n,k) for unordered? I am not sure the answer for ordered.. thank you for the hint but i may need more information to resolve this issue.

Comment: That is right for unordered.  Now for each selection of men, you have c(n,k) choices for the women.  How many joint selections does that give you?  For ordered, once you have made a selection of the $k$ men, how many orders can you put them in?

Comment: 2n! / k!(n-k)!  for unordered
2 n! *k! / k!(n-k)! for ordered, is that correct? thank you

Comment: I am reading your last as $2(n!)/[k!((n-k)!)]$  Please use parentheses to make sure the grouping is right.  The numerator could be $(2n)!$ and the $(n-k)!$ could be in the numerator.  Stacking fractions in $LaTeX$ makes it easier.  A tutorial is [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: With that reading, it is not correct.  For unordered, for each group of men you have $C(n,k)$ groups of women.  As the choices are independent, you multiply them.

Comment: Reading the question again, there is a *much* easier way to do it.  Somehow the group of $2k$ men and women is selected.  This can be done in Ck ways.  To get Bk, you just put each group.  So the ratio is just the number of ways to order $2k$ distinct things.  I think it would be good to follow my original approach, as there will be more problems like this.

Comment: oh, so (2k)! would be the answer, as men and women selection process is the same. thank you so much for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

oh, so (2k)! would be the answer, as men and women selection process is the same. thank you so much for the detailed explanation.

Am i correct?